# I can't add a concrete time specification when making a Present Perfect sentence, but I can do so if I use Past Perfect. Is it correct?

Tags: grammar

For example, would it be okay to say, "A journalist took an interview from the actor who in 1999 had made his debut in [movie title]"?

Comment: Just wondering why not say *"journalist interviewed the actor"* instead of *"journalist took an interview from the actor"*.

Comment: you are right but I don't think the past perfect is necessary, because you have added 1999. It is clear that the interview took place after 1999.

Comment: But isn't Past Perfect obligatory when adding an even earlier action? Do you mean it would be correct to say, "I came home before my wife did"?